# What does XAP stand for?

Tags: silverlight, file-extension

What does XAP stand for? is it an acronym? I know what silverlight XAP file contains but dont know what it stands for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Silverlight **Application Package**

http://www.sharpened.net/extensions/file/xap

http://forums.asp.net/t/1277554.aspx

The X doesn't mean anything.  I've asked, too.

From what I can tell, they didn't want it to look too much like *.ZIP or *.SAP.

Comment: I think, the X stands for XAML, SilverLight use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess **X**ML **A**pplication **P**ackage.

Comment: the X doesn't mean anything. Not everything is XML inside of this package.

Answer (score 0):

When a Silverlight Application is compiled a .xap file is created that contains the application.

Comment: Read the question.  He's asking what it stand for.

Answer (score 0):

A .xap file is basically a compiled Silverlight application. The file is actually a .zip file that contains all the files necessary for the application. Just rename the .xap file to have a .zip extension and then you can open it up to see its contents.

[Anatomy of XAP file](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/03/Silverlight-Anatomy-of-an-XAP-file.aspx)

Comment: Read the question.  He's asking what it stands for.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **XA**ML **P**ackage  --

Answer (score 0):

It means  "Silverlight Application Package" and "Xact Project"

Other meanings without silverlight is http://www.acronym24.com/xap-meaning/