# Silverlight : Why XAP is called XAP and why not something else?

Tags: silverlight

The Silverlight Application Package extension is given as ".xap" which is a zip file. Why is it named XAP? why not something else? Does anyone know why microsoft went with the name XAP? Is there any meaning to XAP? or is XAP an acronym?

Comment: Not sure Microsoft wants Silverlight to be a slap to anyone's faces or anything like that :P

Comment: may be it's from XAML language. huh?

Comment: Voting to close. Subjective, and what difference does it make? And how is that a programming question? It's like asking "Why did your parents name you 'funwithcoding' instead of 'codingforfunandprofit'?"

Comment: @KenWhite according to me it is not a name given just like that. ngen.exe is named because it creates native image. Who knows "XAP" could mean something like "eXtensible Application Package" which means something to programmer.

Comment: [SAP](http://www.sap.com/company/legal/copyright/trademark.epx) is a trademark. `SLAP` can have negative connotations for English speakers. Who wants trouble when one can work around it?

Comment: There is no definitive answer, but a "SAP application" is usually recognised as referring to the products of the German business software company SAP AG. XAP may have simply been chosen to avoid confusion and a potential trademark conflict.

Comment: I really hope they change the name to slap.. Would probably stay as warning for developers and scare away pointy haired bosses :P. Good question thought.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829124/what-does-xap-stand-for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options come to mind:

1. A contraction/abbreviation of XAML Application (or XAML Application Package).
2. A contraction/abbreviation of cross-platform application.

I suspect it may have been the first option or possibly a combination of both.

Answer (score 5):

**SAP**

Trademarked.  German Software Company.  Out.

**SLAP**

> A slap or "smack" is a broad stroke
>   made with the open hand, as opposed to
>   a punch that is made with a closed
>   fist. Slaps are frequently made across
>   the face, but can be also made across
>   hands or any other body part, and can
>   use either the palm of the hand or the
>   back of the hand.

Not the best connotation you need for Silverlight.  Out.

**XAP**

XAML Application Package.  Descriptive.  Nonoffensive.  Beats Apache to the punch nicely.  In.

Comment: I don't believe that a trademark is banned as a file extension, but it certainly would be something Microsoft would want to avoid.